# Slider in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, slider

how to add a slider on cocos2d layer i.e directly on gamescene.m??

Answer (score 9):

you cant add a UISlider directly as a cocos2d node to a layer/scene.

You have to add it as a subview to your cocos2d layer. here is an example:

```
UISlider *sliderCtl = [[UISlider alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 0, 125, 50)];

[sliderCtl addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

sliderCtl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
sliderCtl.value = 0;

[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window]
    addSubview:sliderCtl];
```

Answer (score 1):

For the later version of cocos2d, don't need window in following statement.  That support autorotation.

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:sliderCtl];